# Nested try catch

Tags: java, nested, try-catch

I'm pretty new to java and I have nested Try Catch code that prints 3 times! can you tell me why? 
I get 3 int from Command Line and has to be validated and check if they in range and i am using try and catch. but the answers prints 3 times!

```
// Global Constants
final static int MIN_NUMBER = 1;
final static int MAX_PRIME = 10000;
final static int MAX_FACTORIAL = 12;
final static int MAX_LEAPYEAR = 4000;

// Global Variable
static int a, b, c;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // String[] myNumbers= new String [3];

    // int x =Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        // System.out.print(args[i]+" ");
        validateInput(args[0], args[1], args[2]);

    }
}

// Validate User Input
public static boolean validateInput(String value1, String value2, String value3) {
    boolean isValid = false;

    try {
        try {
            try {
                a = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                if (!withinRange(a, MIN_NUMBER, MAX_PRIME)) {
                    System.out.println(
                            "The entered value " + value1
                            + " is out of range [1 TO 10000].");
                }
                isValid = true;         

            } catch (Exception ex) { 
                System.out.println(
                        "The entered value " + value1
                        + " is not a valid integer.  Please try again.");
            }   

            b = Integer.parseInt(value2);
            if (!withinRange(b, MIN_NUMBER, MAX_FACTORIAL)) {
                System.out.println(
                        "The entered value " + value2
                        + " is out of range [1 TO 12].");
            }
            isValid = true; 
        } catch (Exception ex) { 
            System.out.println(
                    "The entered value " + value2
                    + " is not a valid integer.  Please try again.");
        }

        c = Integer.parseInt(value3);
        if (!withinRange(c, MIN_NUMBER, MAX_LEAPYEAR)) {
            System.out.println(
                    "The entered value " + value3
                    + " is out of range [1 TO 4000].");
        }
        isValid = true; 
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        System.out.println(
                "The entered value " + value3
                + " is not a valid integer.  Please try again.");
    }   

    return isValid;

}

// Check the value within the specified range
private static boolean withinRange(int value, int min, int max) {
    boolean isInRange = true; 

    if (value < min || value > max) {
        isInRange = false; 
    }
    return isInRange;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to "return invalid" for the first validation that failed. Otherwise it will keep trying with the other values as well. It keeps trying the other values because the exception propagation is suppressed (catch without [re-]throw). I would *rewrite* the above code to *not* use nested try-catch blocks as a first-step in simplification ..

Comment: It works without try and catch, but it is required to have try and catch :(

Comment: Well, if nested try-catch blocks are required (ick!), consider moving the subsequent logic *inside* the try - that is, move it from the catch. If an exception is throw it will then skip the subsequent code (as it jumps to the catch); in this case, since the subsequent code was inside the try it will enter at most one catch (and print at most one message).

Comment: Please rewrite `withinRange()` to something like `boolean withinRange(int value, int min, int max) { return (value >= min && value <= max); }`. What you have hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is printed 3 times, since you have put the validateInput method call into a `for` loop in `main()`, which runs it three times in case of three arguments.

Comment: +1 - Other answers have good suggestions in general, but this actually answers the OP's question.

Comment: @Gabor Liptak what i suppose to do?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest writing the `validateInput` method to validate a *single* string. Add two arguments for the min and max allowed int values.

```
public static boolean validateInput(String value, int minValue, int maxValue) {
    try {
        integer intVal = Integer.parseInt(value);
        if (intVal < minVal || intVal > maxValue) {
            System.out.println("The entered value " + value
                + " is out of range [" + minValue + " TO " + maxValue + "].");

            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("The entered value " + value
            + " is not a valid integer. Please try again");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: then what i should do for other entries? bcoz each has separate error notes!!

Comment: @Niloo - The error notes looked the same for all three to me (once the min and max values are parameterized). If you call this for each entry in turn, it should behave exactly you want.

Comment: Thank you all :) it's fixed i took my validateunput from my for loop from main method and is working fine :)

Comment: What if i have try{...}catch{try{showpopup("server getting crazy")}{catch{}}}....this is Android specific scenario when we try to pass messages and some times messenger target isn't valid...

Comment: @VarunTewari - I'm not sure what you mean by "messenger target isn't valid". In Android, you need a `Context` to show a pop-up (`AlertDialog`, etc.). If necessary, a `Context` argument can be added to the `validateInput` method. Alternatively (and more cleanly) the `validateInput` method could be rewritten to return a `String` containing the error message or `null` if the validation succeeded. Then the calling code could display the message via whatever mechanism it chose.